# How to control placement of icons of documents saved to the desktop in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, desktop-environments, wayland

Often in my work I will save documents to the desktop directory temporarily so their icons are readily available to me on the desktop to click on.  When I save documents to the desktop, their icons appear on the primary monitor.  That is fine.  But, they are placed starting in the top left corner of the primary monitor.  I'd like for them to be placed starting in the top right corner of the primary monitor instead.  How do I make that change happen?